# Unable to execute a Job Sequentially - Azure Pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have been testing out Azure DevOps Pipeline. I was not having any Parallel jobs configured in my pipeline but still, it says

> "##[error]No hosted parallelism has been purchased or granted. To
> request a free parallelism grant, please fill out the following form
> [https://aka.ms/azpipelines-parallelism-request"](https://aka.ms/azpipelines-parallelism-request%22).

I am trying to understand this in detail, when I have a normal sequential job why do I get this error message?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 'No hosted parallelism has been purchased or granted. To request a free parallelism grant, please fill out the following form [https://aka.ms/azpipelines-parallelism-request'](https://aka.ms/azpipelines-parallelism-request%27)

Based on the error message, the issue should be related to the change in Azure Pipelines Grants:

[Change in Azure Pipelines Grant for Private Projects](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/change-in-azure-pipelines-grant-for-private-projects/)

[Sprint 184 release notes - Changes to Azure Pipelines free grants](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2021/sprint-184-update#azure-pipelines-1)

The change is aiming to avoid abuse, especially crypto mining. Generally, this change only impacts new organizations and new projects.

Earlier this year, this change has been applied to public projects:

[Change in Azure Pipelines Grant for Public Projects](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/change-in-azure-pipelines-grant-for-public-projects/)

[Sprint 183 release notes - Change in process for obtaining free pipelines grant in public projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2021/sprint-183-update#change-in-process-for-obtaining-free-pipelines-grant-in-public-projects)

You can request your free Azure Pipelines Grants by submitting [a request form](https://forms.office.com/pages/responsepage.aspx?id=v4j5cvGGr0GRqy180BHbR63mUWPlq7NEsFZhkyH8jChUMlM3QzdDMFZOMkVBWU5BWFM3SDI2QlRBSC4u). After seeding the request, there may have a few days delay before you gain the free grants.

For more detailed info, you could refer to this doc about [Configure and pay for parallel jobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/licensing/concurrent-jobs?preserve-view=true&tabs=ms-hosted&view=azure-devops)